# Securing Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

What options are there to secure Windows Azure Table storage?

Is there anyway to create an ACL? e.g. A readonly account, an admin account etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, at the last PDC10 Mark Russinovich mentioned that this is his biggest concern how to gain permissions based on permissions, groups, etc.. I could even try to find that interview, so I don't think you can do much about that in the current version.

UPDATE: it was actually Channel 9 Live interview - [here](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/44612cbe-f567-437a-9e13-d3860d9562c7) we go.. at 5:34

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in encrypting your Azure Table storage, take a look at this open source code I made:  http://azuretableencrypt.codeplex.com

All data is transparently encrypted and decrypted.